# ¿Cómo ordenar fechas con formato dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt en javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, date-format

Tengo el grid de **paramquery** que solo ordena la fecha tomando los primeros dígitos dd; ya intenté con **dataType:"date"** y **format :"dd/mm/yyyy"**, pero sigue sin ordenarlas.

Esta fecha siempre la mantiene abajo (13/02/2018 02:55:00 PM) y 24/08/2017 09:40:00 AM la mantiene arriba.

Comment: Agrega un [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
let fechas = ['13/02/2018 02:55:00 PM', '24/08/2017 09:40:00 AM',  '01/04/2011 10:55:00 AM'];

Array.prototype._w3skulls = function(){
    let res = new Array();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        let f = this[i][0].split('/');
        let aux = f[2];

        f[2] = f[0];
        f[0] = aux; 

        this[i][0] = f[0].concat('-' + f[1] + '-' + f[2]);

        let h  = this[i][1].split(':');

        if(this[i][2] == 'PM'){
            h[0] = parseInt(h[0]) + 12;
        }

        this[i][1] = h[0] + ':' + h[1] + ':' + h[2];
        res[i] = this[i][0] + ' '+ this[i][1];
    }
    return res;
};

function sortDates(fechas){
    let f_aux = fechas.map(function(elem, index, array) {
        return elem.split(' ');
    });

    let res = f_aux._w3skulls();

    let w3 = new Array();
    res.forEach(function(item, index){
        w3[index] = new Date(item);
    });

    w3.sort();
    for(let i = 0; i < w3.length; i++){
        let dia = '';  let mes = ''; let hora =''; let min = ''; let seg ='';
        let am = 'am';
        if(w3[i].getDate() < 10){
            dia = '0' + w3[i].getDate();
        }else{
            dia = w3[i].getDate();
        }

        if((w3[i].getMonth() + 1) < 10){
            mes = '0' + (w3[i].getMonth() + 1);
        }else{
            mes = (w3[i].getMonth() + 1);
        }

        if((w3[i].getHours() - 12) > 10){
            hora = '0' + w3[i].getHours();
            am = 'pm';
        }else{
            hora = w3[i].getHours();
        }

        if(w3[i].getMinutes() < 10){
            min = '0' + w3[i].getMinutes();
        }else{
            min =w3[i].getMinutes();
        }

        if(w3[i].getSeconds() < 10){
            seg = '0' + w3[i].getSeconds();
        }else{
            seg = w3[i].getSeconds();
        }

        w3[i] = dia + '/' + mes + '/' + w3[i].getFullYear() + ' ' + hora + ':' + min + ':' + seg + ' ' + am.toUpperCase();
    }
    return w3;
}

console.log(sortDates(fechas));
```

Comment: El script formatea los datos del array a un formato que pueda ser convertible en una fecha, tiene en cuenta los AM y PM. (_w3skulls). En un segundo paso, se ordena el array de fechas con sort(), para devolver más tarde el mismo array de origen pero ordenado por fecha ascendente.